# What does 挨拶ナマ mean?

Tags: slang

I can't find the definition of ナマ.

Comment: Welcome to Japanese.SE! Do you think you could add some context, such as the original sentence? That tends to help quite a bit with questions like this. Thanks!

Comment: 挨拶ナマ doesn't mean anything by itself. It should be part of 舞台挨拶ナマ放送, 舞台挨拶ナマ出演, or インドの挨拶ナマステ etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to give a definitive answer, given the total absence of context, but なま basically means "raw", as in なまざかな. However, it has a whole range of extended meanings: the two I think of first with 挨拶 are the "live" in "live broadcast", or the なま in なまの声, meaning "without a microphone". Or again, it might mean something like "unrehearsed" or "impromptu".